# Swift: create module (namespace)

Tags: ios, swift, namespaces

Hy guys,

Do you know how can I create a module(namespace) in swift ? For example in C# we have **namespace** keyword, but in Objective-C there is no such thing, there we named our classes with the prefix of the folder they were located in. Shall I use the same approach in **swift** or do you know some other way to achieve namespacing in swift.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I will either rename my classes to have a prefix of two capital letters like NSString, UIView and other classes from Objective-C do or I will wrap them in structs.

Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using Frameworks which is newly introduced in iOS 8 for namespace-ing, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Hhmmm, I have min iOS runtime version set to 7.1 for the project